# how can I apply css style to select focus?

Tags: css, angular, select, focus

I have a select input field, I want to apply colors when the field is focus, but not working.

I am trying to apply this css to an Angular component and it works for other input fields such as:

```
input[type='text']:focus{
border-color:red;
}
```

but the same does not work for select

```
select:focus{
border-color:red;
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075) inset, 0 0 8px #5e9b1f;
outline: 0 none;
}
```

select drop down should get border color just like text field does.

Comment: Use `(focus)` event in angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's working but you can't see the border due to the outline

```
 select:focus {
     border-color:red;
     outline:none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Mohamedfathy/5hjwfm82/4/

Comment: yeah, I am using the outine: 0 none;

Comment: your updated code will work fine, do u still have a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.select div:hover, .same-as-selected {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

for reference - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp